# How to do line by line concurrency limiting in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read a file line by line and do some async function using the data read. I need to limit the concurrency of this. I know how to read line by line, and how to do the concurrency using modules, but I don't know how to put them together. I'm using the line-by-line and throat modules.

Here's what I tried so far without success:

```
// modules
const CONCURRENCY = 5 
const throat = require('throat')(CONCURRENCY)
const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line')
lr = new LineByLineReader('urls.txt')

throat(() => { 
  lr.on('line', function (line) {

      return main(line) // this is an async function that returns a promise
      Promise.resolve()

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `throat` inside of the `line` callback

```
const CONCURRENCY = 5
const throat = require('throat')
const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line')
lr = new LineByLineReader('urls.txt')

lr.on('line', throat(CONCURRENCY, main))
```

Also, you can use node's builtin [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module, instead of `line-by-line`:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

readline.
  createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream('urls.txt')}).
  on('line', throat(CONCURRENCY, main))
```